# MiKTeX hyphenation not working on MacOS. (There is no hyphenation.)

Tags: miktex, hyphenation, macos

I have just got my first Mac and I'm trying to setup Latex on my system. Everything seems to work fine, except that MiKTeX refuses to hyphenate words, and as a result my rows overflows the width of the page when I have too long words. I get warning messages like:

```
Overfull \hbox (33.25203pt too wide) in paragraph
```

And the right margin is destroyed:
[image]
It doesn't matter which compiler I use. I have tried XeLaTex, PdfLaTeX, LaTeX, LuaLaTeX, and Latexmk.

It doesn't matter which incisions I have. In the above example the .tex file is very simple:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\begin{document}
Loremipsum dolorsit amet, vixerror choroveniam at. Novix evertiturvituperatoribus. Unumintellegam estno, omnislobortis reformidansnec te. Nullam vituperatoribus usuex. Sitte meliusdebitis, eusit laboresinermis repudiare. Utamurminimum iusno, hisquando facilisisin, eigraeci laoreet eam. Seaei dictasperfecto, integreeruditi copiosaenequi. Cumei dicamfacilisi erroribus. Dictacongue integrevisut, prodebitis inermisluptatumte. Netale constituamhis, namad nulla necessitatibus. Videinermis hisid, teassum nostronominavi nam, aliquamindoctum theophrastus nevel. Te sitdicuntepicuri.
\end{document}
```

I have used two different editors (TexPad and TexStudio) and both have the same problem.

I suspected that there were some missing language files. But in MiKTeX Console everything seems fine to me.
[image]

The log file doesn't seem to contain anything useful:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (MiKTeX 2.9.6800) (preloaded format=xelatex 2018.9.26)  26 SEP 2018 10:41
entering extended mode
**./base.tex
(base.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5

("/Users/eric/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/
article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class

("/Users/eric/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/
size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (base.aux)
\openout1 = `base.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TU/lmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.

Overfull \hbox (33.25203pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--5
[]\TU/lmr/m/n/10 Loremipsum dolorsit amet, vixerror choroveniam at. Novix evert
iturvituperatoribus.
 []


Overfull \hbox (2.522pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--5
\TU/lmr/m/n/10 Unumintellegam estno, omnislobortis reformidansnec te. Nullam vi
tuperatoribus
 []


Overfull \hbox (14.89603pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--5
\TU/lmr/m/n/10 iusno, hisquando facilisisin, eigraeci laoreet eam. Seaei dictas
perfecto, integreeruditi
 []


Overfull \hbox (10.06203pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--5
\TU/lmr/m/n/10 copiosaenequi. Cumei dicamfacilisi erroribus. Dictacongue integr
evisut, prodebitis
 []


Overfull \hbox (12.71202pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--5
\TU/lmr/m/n/10 inermisluptatumte. Netale constituamhis, namad nulla necessitati
bus. Videinermis
 []

[1

] (base.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 203 strings out of 429720
 2087 string characters out of 3179525
 58063 words of memory out of 3000000
 4157 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3648 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 0 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 22i,4n,17p,592b,107s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on base.pdf (1 page).
```

Comment: something is very wrong with your setup. the US English tables do not usually hyphenate the pseudo-latin lipsum text well, but they do manage to hyphenate that example with no overfull lines. Can you show the log file you get from that example. The US hyphenation tables are not an optional part of a tex distribution so they should always be installed.

Comment: I get the output you show if I disable hyphenation with, for example `\hyphenpenalty=10000` in the preamble, so you could add `\showthe\hyphenpenalty` and report the value that TeX says....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I added the log file to the post.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the output from hyphen penalty:
    > 50.
    l.4 \showthe\hyphenpenalty

Comment: your log file **does* show something useful, it seems to show you have no languages loaded (it should say something like  `LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.15> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.` at the top did you get an error when miktex made the formats?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Great!! Thanks. It was hard for _me_ to see that something is missing. I got no errors when compiling the PDF. (Or was that what you were asking?) Then, how do I load Babel and/or hyphenation patterns?

Comment: No you can't fix it in a normal document run your latex format seems corrupt, I don't know miktex but you must be able to tell it to remake the format files (`fmtutil-sys --all` in texlive) then it should either load the hyphenation tables or at least give you an error message saying why not.

Comment: incidentally the vast majority of tex users on the mac will be using MacTeX (texlive)  any particular reason to be using miktex (which until very recently was windows only)?

Comment: The US hyphenation patterns (`hyphen.tex`) are a part of the `knuth-lib` package. You should make sure that this package is installed and then run `initexmf --mklangs` followed by `initexmf --dump` to update the format files.

Comment: Wow! That worked! Thanks @ChristianSchenk. Running those terminal commands prompted installation of some packages (of which some had the names including "hyphen"). Now it works! PS. I already had the package, but I begun by reinstalling it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, I was running MiKTeX on my previous Win machine. So just for consistency I thought I would continue with that. But I'm also downloading MacTeX now (even though I solved the issue, see above). Can I ask an off topic question about how they would differ? In speed, and in the way they typeset.

Comment: don't ask me, Christian would know more about it:-) I have used texlive/tetex/unixtex for 30 years and never used miktex so can't really give an objective comparison:-)

Comment: I can confirm that @ChristianSchenk's solved the problem for me too, although I don't know why :)

Comment: @ChristianSchenk I got the same error as the OP, but `initexmf --dump` failed with an error message. The log files pointed me to each other (initexmf.log->miktex-makefmt.out->miktex-makefmt.log) and the last one said "miktex-luatex failed on luatex.ini". I installed the miktex-luatex package and ran initexmf again and it worked. I suggest that initexmf shouldn't attempt to run luatex if it is not installed, or install it itself. I suggest that the knuth-lib package be automatically installed so that hyphenation is available without user troubleshooting.

Comment: @ChristianSchenk also the hyph-utf8 package should be automatically installed.

Comment: I have tried all of the troubleshooting steps above, but `initexmf --dump` still fails. Now it is looking for `luahbtex` which I couldn't figure out how to install (`luatex` and `lualatex` are there). I am guessing the answer to the OP at this point should be: use TeXLive :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the (at least) third person to have this problem solved thanks to Christian Schenk's comments to the question, I thought I'd post it as an answer so others won't miss it.

> The US hyphenation patterns (hyphen.tex) are a part of the knuth-lib package. You should make sure that this package is installed and then run `initexmf --mklangs` followed by `initexmf --dump` to update the format files.

Just run those two commands from the terminal (second one takes a few minutes) - worked for me even from a non-admin user.