# No automatic hyphenation

Tags: texstudio, babel, hyphenation

I am writing a document in English, and no words are being hyphenated unless I include them in a `\hyphenation{*}` command. For instance, the word 'government' protrudes into the margin unless I include `\hyphenation{gov-ern-ment}` in the preamble.

I don't think this can be an issue with `\hyphenpenalty` or `\lefthyphenmin` and `\righthyphenmin`, since once words are included in the `\hyphenation{*}` command everything works fine (and because I've tried fiddling with these parameters and it's not fixed anything). I've also tried putting `\usepackage[english]{babel}` in the preamble and that's not fixed anything. I've just reinstalled MiKTeX and updated all my packages, so I don't think that can be an issue.

EDIT 4:
This seems to be problem with TeXStudio, as my minimal example works fine in the command line, using `pdflatex hyphenation-example`.

EDIT:
I'm using document class `book`, with subfiles, though I've had a similar problem with the document class `article` in the past.

Here's my full preamble. I had this issue before I defined any custom commands, so the packages section is likely the most relevant.

```
% LATEX PARAMETERS_________________________________________________________________________
%default values are 50
\hyphenpenalty = 50 % lower means more hyphenation
\tolerance = 50 % lower means less stretching between words, more likelihood of jagged edge, and more hyphenation
\lefthyphenmin = 2
\righthyphenmin = 2


% PACKAGES_________________________________________________________________________________

% general functionality
\usepackage{amsmath} % matrices
\usepackage{amssymb} % fancy maths letters
\usepackage{breqn} % equations over several lines
\usepackage{graphicx} % import figures
\usepackage{caption} % caption figures
\usepackage{subcaption} % subfigures
\captionsetup{font={small},labelfont={bf},labelsep=space}
\usepackage{xparse} % needed for shortenthis command and commands with an if-then structure
\usepackage[pagestyles,explicit,raggedright]{titlesec} % change title style
\usepackage{needspace} % insert pagebreak if not enough space
\usepackage[nottoc,notlot,notlof]{tocbibind} % inlcude bibliography in toc
\usepackage{subfiles}

% fonts
\usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign} % set font to BT Charter
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % font encoding
\newcommand{\sansfont}{\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont} % command to set font to TeX Gyre Heros

% ornaments
\usepackage{adforn} % fleurons
\newcommand{\ico}{\includegraphics[height=0.8 em]{Icosahedron}}
\newcommand{\flower}{\begin{center}\Large\adfflowerright\end{center}}

% draft formatting
\usepackage{setspace} % line spacing
\usepackage{lineno} % line numbering

% page formatting
\usepackage[left = 35mm, right = 25mm, top = 30mm, bottom = 30 mm, headsep = 12mm, footskip = 15mm]{geometry} % page margins

% making diagrams
\usepackage{tikz} % make diagrams in LaTeX
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta} % set arrow appearance
\tikzset{>={Latex[width=3mm,length=3mm]}}
\pgfdeclarelayer{bg} % for loops
\pgfsetlayers{bg,main}

% references
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\doi}[1]{\textsc{doi}: \href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}} % allows underscores in dois

% colors
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{vp}{HTML}{440154} % viridis purple
\definecolor{vb}{HTML}{33638D} % viridis blue
\definecolor{vg}{HTML}{3CBB75} % viridis green
\definecolor{vy}{HTML}{FDE725} % viridis yellow
\definecolor{IBMb}{HTML}{648FFF} % IBM blue
\definecolor{IBMr}{HTML}{DC267F} % IBM red
\definecolor{IBMy}{HTML}{FFB000} % IBM yellow
\definecolor{IBMp}{HTML}{785EF0} % IBM purple


% COMMANDS_________________________________________________________________________________

% define the 'shortenthis' command, which I use in the definition abbreviations. sourced from Manuel on StackExchange, in an answer posted on 2014-03-01
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\shortenthis{ m }
    {\shorten_this:n { #1 }}
\seq_new:N \l_shorten_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \shorten_this:n #1
    {\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_shorten_seq { ~ } { #1 }
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_shorten_seq
    {\tl_head:n { ##1 } }}
\ExplSyntaxOff

% define documentstyle option 'draft'. in draft documents certain commands will behave differently
\newif\if@myfilerough
\DeclareOption{rough}{\@myfileroughtrue}

\ProcessOptions\relax

\if@myfilerough
  % in a rough rough text shows up and is noted in the margin
  \newcommand{\rough}[1]{$<$#1$>$\marginpar{\color{magenta}\textbf{rough}}}
  \newcommand{\citerough}[1]{[[#1]]\marginpar{\color{blue}\textbf{cite}}}
  % in a rough definitions are noted in the margin, with an optional argument for an abbreviation
  \NewDocumentCommand{\term}{o m}{%
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}%
      {\emph{#2}\marginpar{\textbf{``\shortenthis{#2}''}}}%
      {\emph{#2} (#1)\marginpar{\textbf{``#1''}}}%
  }
  % roughs have 1.5x spacing and line numbers
  \onehalfspacing
  \linenumbers
\else
  % in a non-rough rough text is not shown
  \newcommand{\rough}[1]{}
  \newcommand{\citerough}[1]{}
  % in a non-rough definitions are emphasised but are not noted in the margin
  \NewDocumentCommand{\term}{o m}{%
    {\emph{#2}}%
  }
\fi

%for use at end of chapters to make the next page occur on the left
\newcommand*\cleartoleftpage{%
  \clearpage
  \ifodd\value{page}\hbox{}\newpage\fi
}


% FORMATTING________________________________________________________________________________

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\raggedright\sansfont\singlespacing\Huge}{\thechapter\hspace{20pt}\ico\hspace{20pt}}{0pt}{\Huge #1}[]%

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\needspace{0.5in}\sansfont\singlespacing}{}{0pt}{\LARGE #1 \Large \hfill \ico~\thesection}[]%

\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\needspace{0.5in}\sansfont\singlespacing}{}{0pt}{\Large #1 \large \hfill \ico~\thesubsection}[]%

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{\needspace{0.5in}\sansfont\singlespacing\normalsize}{}{0pt}{\large #1 \hfill}[]%

% Redefine headers
\newpagestyle{main}{% 
  \sethead[\sansfont \thepage \hspace{.7cm} \textsl{\chaptertitle}][][]
  {}{}{\sansfont \textsl{\thesection~\ {\ico} \ \sectiontitle} \hspace{.7cm} \thepage}
  \setfoot{}{}{}
} % Define page style main
\pagestyle{main} % Use page style main

\renewpagestyle{plain}{% 
  \setfoot{}{}{}
} % Define page style plain (first pages of chapters etc)

\title{thesis}
\author{ben}

\endinput
```

EDIT 2:

Here's a minimal example, with the textwidth set very low to show that hyphenation isn't working:

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
\textwidth=4cm
\usepackage[english,showlanguages]{babel}

\begin{document}
A pandemic is an event in which a disease spreads over a very large area, often crossing national borders. Pandemics often infect large numbers of people, can cause many deaths , and have negative effects on trade and the world economy. It is due to the large scale of the negative effects of pandemics that pandemic preparedness is seen as an important public health activity, despite the low frequency of pandemics in comparison to other disease outbreaks. Factors implicated in pandemic risk include travel, high population density, and changing agricultural practices.
\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX PDF output showing failure of hyphenation]

And here's the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (MiKTeX 21.6) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.7.15)  15 JUL 2021 16:17
entering extended mode
**./hyphenation-example.tex
(hyphenation-example.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2021-07-12>
(/Users/user/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/b
ook.cls
Document Class: book 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class

(/Users/user/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/base/b
k10.clo
File: bk10.clo 2021/02/12 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count182
\c@chapter=\count183
\c@section=\count184
\c@subsection=\count185
\c@subsubsection=\count186
\c@paragraph=\count187
\c@subparagraph=\count188
\c@figure=\count189
\c@table=\count190
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
)
(/Users/user/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/generic/babe
l/babel.sty
Package: babel 2021/06/28 3.61 The Babel package
<*languages>
</languages>

(/Users/user/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/generic/babe
l/babel.def
File: babel.def 2021/06/28 3.61 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count191
\U@D=\dimen139
\l@unhyphenated=\language1

(/Users/user/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/generic/babe
l/txtbabel.def)
\bbl@readstream=\read2
)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count192

*************************************
* Local config file bblopts.cfg used
*

(/Users/user/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/arabi/
bblopts.cfg
File: bblopts.cfg 2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of
 babel
)
(/Users/user/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/babel-
english/english.ldf
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
))
(/Users/user/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/install/tex/latex/l3back
end/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2021-07-12 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count193
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
) (hyphenation-example.aux)
\openout1 = `hyphenation-example.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.

Overfull \hbox (3.46695pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--7
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 over a very large area, often|
 []


Overfull \hbox (6.6892pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--7
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 Pandemics often infect large|
 []


Overfull \hbox (9.60585pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--7
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 numbers of people, can cause|
 []


Overfull \hbox (24.52258pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--7
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 many deaths , and have negative|
 []


Overfull \hbox (11.85583pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--7
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 effects on trade and the world|
 []


Overfull \hbox (3.55031pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--7
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 seen as an important public|
 []


Overfull \hbox (3.21696pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--7
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 low frequency of pandemics|
 []


Overfull \hbox (14.74475pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--7
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 in comparison to other disease|
 []


Overfull \hbox (15.2911pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--7
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 outbreaks. Factors implicated|
 []


Overfull \hbox (19.63367pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--7
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 in pandemic risk include travel,|
 []


Overfull \hbox (8.13373pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--7
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 high population density, and|
 []


Overfull \hbox (21.05035pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--7
\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 changing agricultural practices. |
 []

[1{/Users/user/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/texmfs/data/pdftex/config/pdf
tex.map}

] (hyphenation-example.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1207 strings out of 480807
 19477 string characters out of 2898544
 325395 words of memory out of 3000000
 18943 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 403783 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 0 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 40i,5n,52p,619b,149s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</Users/user/Library/Application Support/MiKTeX/te
xmfs/install/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on hyphenation-example.pdf (1 page, 18944 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 11 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Adding a `\hyphenation{*}` command means that hyphenation can occur.

```
\documentclass{book}
\textwidth=4cm
\usepackage[english,showlanguages]{babel}
\hyphenation{of-ten}

\begin{document}
A pandemic is an event in which a disease spreads over a very large area, often crossing national borders. Pandemics often infect large numbers of people, can cause many deaths , and have negative effects on trade and the world economy. It is due to the large scale of the negative effects of pandemics that pandemic preparedness is seen as an important public health activity, despite the low frequency of pandemics in comparison to other disease outbreaks. Factors implicated in pandemic risk include travel, high population density, and changing agricultural practices.
\end{document}
```

[image: LaTeX PDF output showing the word 'often' hyphenated]

Edit 3:
Screenshot of commands in TeXStudio[image: screenshot of commands in TeXstudio, in particular the pdflatex command being pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex]

Comment: Does your document by any chance load a package, such as `hyphenat`, that suppresses all hyphenation by default?

Comment: Please do tell us which document class you employ and which packages are loaded in the preamble.

Comment: texstudio and texmaker are unrelated to this problem, they are just the editors you use to write the file, latex will give the same hyphenations whatever editor you use.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've put the info above. I'm not using hyphenat or anything similar (as far as I'm aware...)

Comment: you have `\hyphenpenalty = 1000 % lower means more hyphenation` the default is 50, so this will make hyphenation much more unlikely to happen that is, this comment `%default values are 1000` is wrong.

Comment: Hi David, I've tried lots of different values (down to 1) and none of them cause hyphenation to occur. Also, even at ```\hyphenpenalty = 1000```, plenty of hyphenation happens for words included in ```\hyphenation{*}```. (thanks for correcting me on the default values though!)

Comment: Make a small example only with `\documentclass{book}` and perhaps \textwidth=4cm (to get more hyphenation) and then add some text. If it works, add some stuff from your preamble until it breaks again. If the small example doesn't work, show it along with its log-file.

Comment: You have not provided any example, so we can't really comment on the specific linebreaking you are seeing. Your example should be a complete small document that shows lack of hyphenation, preferably without unrelated packages , breqn, tikz, .... to ease tracing,

Comment: I've put in a full minimal example above, plus the log file. Even with very low ```\hyphenpenalty``` and ```\tolerance```, no hyphenation occurs.

Comment: Add `\usepackage[english,showlanguages]{babel}` and then show which languages are mentioned in the log (at best update the log)

Comment: Thanks Ulrike, I've updated the example and the log output above as you suggested.

Comment: Why are you doing `\tolerance = 1`?

Comment: Hi pst, I set the tolerance low to try to force hyphenation. I get similar results with higher tolerances, though slightly less dramatic.

Comment: I do get hyphenation with your minimal example, so something strange is going on here. A long shot: how do you compile your documents? Do you type `(lua/pdf/xe)latex whatever` in the terminal or do you press a button in an editor?

Comment: Hi Ian, I suspected it would be something strange haha. I press Build & View in TeXStudio.

Comment: OK, try opening a terminal/command window, cd to the folder containing your files and do `pdflatex hyphenation-example`. Do you get any hyphenation?

Comment: In your log file it says "0 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191". That's not normal! Is is strange always or "just" with Babel? To get yet another variable out of this, can you also remove your babel settings and see if you get the normal TeX hyphenation without it?

Comment: Ian, I tried running from the command line and that fixes the problem (amazing!) Any idea why?

Comment: Integrated development environments are the work of Satan. Somewhere in the menus, there will be a dialogue box that shows you what command and options etc. your editor is passing to the engine. Can you add a screenshot showing what's there?

Comment: I'm using pdflatex and I believe the command option is ```pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex```, but I'll add a screenshot too. Running this command in the terminal doesn't reproduce the problem.

Comment: No I am not sure. Would not using MiKTeX help?

Comment: the log you show shows the first overfull rule after often which is not consistent with the output that you show nor with the result that I get when I run your example.

Comment: if you get a different result on the commandline you have two tex systems installed and your path on the terminal is not the path set in your editor.

Comment: on the terminal which pdflatex do you get, what does `type -all pdflatex`  report?

Comment: I would guess this is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/452572/miktex-hyphenation-not-working-on-macos-there-is-no-hyphenation  note that the same comment  applies. the vast majority of Mac users will be using MacTeX (texlive) not miktex (which is a port of the popular windows miktex tex implementation to macos)

Comment: You should use @UlrikeFischer if you want me to see a ping. But beside this, it is clear that something is wrong with your miktex installation and you should follow the tipp of Christian Schenk in the link David sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this was due to the fact that TeXStudio was using MiKTeX rather than TeX Live. MiKTeX had not properly installed the hyphenation dictionary. I solved this by uninstalling MiKTeX and reinstalling TeX Live, after which TeXStudio automatically switched to using TeX Live and successfully built a document with correct hyphenation.

Answer (score 2):

The `microtype` also can help to reduce hyphens, and better distribute the  interword spaces, but note that the abuse of `shrink` and `stretch` options could be worse that hyphens and the overfull \hbox.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm,paperwidth=5cm,paperheight=12
cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,showlanguages]{babel}
\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion=true, shrink=55, stretch=55, 
tracking=true, kerning=true, spacing=true, 
final]{microtype}
\hyphenation{he-alth}
\newcommand\zz{%
A pandemic is an event in which a disease spreads over a very large
area, often crossing national borders. Pandemics often infect large
numbers of people, can cause many deaths, and have negative effects
on trade and the world economy. It is due to the large scale of the
negative effects of pandemics that pandemic preparedness is seen as an
important public health activity, despite the low frequency of
pandemics in comparison to other disease outbreaks. Factors implicated
in pandemic risk include travel, high population density, and changing
agricultural practices.}
\begin{document}
\section*{Microtype}
\zz
\clearpage
\microtypesetup{expansion=false}
\microtypesetup{protrusion=false}
\microtypesetup{kerning=false}
\microtypesetup{tracking=false}
\section*{Emergency}
\zz\emergencystretch2em
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 yes it's better with microtype (although the OP has since clarified in comments that the format has no hyphenation patterns loaded  so neither of our answers would help). I did consider if I ought to use geometry rather than forcing the page size settings:-)

Comment: Thanks for this example, I hadn't heard about microtype. I'm afraid this doesn't adress my original problem, which as David says is that no hyphenation patterns were loaded.

Answer (score 1):

TeX can set text in such narrow columns but you have to adjust things a bit, in particular allow more white space stretching, as even with hyphenation there simply are not enough breakpoints with the standard white space constraints. Here are three possibilities.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\textwidth=4cm
\oddsidemargin=.1cm
\evensidemargin=.1cm
\usepackage[english,showlanguages]{babel}
\hyphenation{of-ten}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\pdfpagewidth=8cm
\newcommand\zz{%
A pandemic is an event in which a disease spreads over a very large
area, often crossing national borders. Pandemics often infect large
numbers of people, can cause many deaths , and have negative effects
on trade and the world economy. It is due to the large scale of the
negative effects of pandemics that pandemic preparedness is seen as an
important public health activity, despite the low frequency of
pandemics in comparison to other disease outbreaks. Factors implicated
in pandemic risk include travel, high population density, and changing
agricultural practices.}

\begin{document}

\section*{Sloppy}
\begin{sloppypar}
\zz
\end{sloppypar}

\clearpage

\section*{Emergencystretch}
{\emergencystretch=2em \zz\par}

\clearpage

\section*{Ragged2e}
{\RaggedRight\zz\par}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `\tolerance = 1` you are asking TeX to only make super nice lines – better lines than it normally can do with this text. So it will fail over and over again, and when it fails anyway you will not get nice output. If you add the draft option, like `\documentclass[draft]{book}` you will see which lines it has failed with. This is what I get:

[image]

(By the way, notice that there are indeed some hyphenations there.)
If you just remove your settings for`\tolerance` and `\hyphenpenalty` you will get better result, with more OK lines, but still several failed lines with these very narrow lines:

[image]

Nice in the beginning, but then it is too hard. You will indeed see more hyphenations with the exception patterns you defined, since they add some hyphenation points that TeXs algorithm doesn't find. For example it hyphenates only *pan-demic* and doesn't hyphenate *travel*.

So maybe this line of explanation does nothing about the problem you started with, because when trying to fix that, whatever it was, you added settings that don't work well.

Comment: I included ```\tolerance=1``` only to make the example more extreme. I do not plan to use this very low tolerance in my final output. Even with default ```\tolerance``` there is still no hyphenation, and even with very low tolerance, adding words to ```\hyphenation{*}``` causes hyphenation.

Comment: I get hyphenation. I've added some output to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for this clear explanation of the role of ```\tolerance```. As I said, I don't plan to use anything like this extreme value in the final document, or even in my drafts, I just included it to illustrate the problem I was having and that changing ```\tolerance``` doesn't fix it. I will edit the original question to show the case when ```\tolerance``` has its default value.